# Payment through webview controller in IOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, stripe-payments

I am making an app through which people can add fund via their credit card for some social purpose. I am doing it in `UIWebview` controller provided in `objective-c`. Can anyone suggest me that

1) Use of `UIWebview` for payment purpose is allowed in IOS

2) if yes then apple can still deduct its 30% share using this method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please select an answer and let us know if you have any additional questions

Answer (score 6):

If the payment is not for a digital content/service such as an added feature to your app, you can make use of any payment gateways using an embedded web view. Charity will not comes under IAP(In app purchase). So it is safe to use any payment system. 30% deduction is only for IAP.

Comment: Hi @Anil, is eTicket considered as a digital content/service? I want to create a app to allow users to register for events and purchase tickets within the app. Will it get rejected by app store?

Comment: @user1872384 eTicket is not a digital content/Service(ticket for movies, bus ticket) apps like Paytm using their own payment systems. So you can also. Go ahead

Comment: I want to allow payment in web view for registration and it charges minimal amount, Without registration user can't login to app. is it allowed?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what it's for. If it's to unlock a feature, it's not allowed and your app would be rejected. If it's to buy a physical object, it is allowed and Apple wouldn't take a 30% cut of it.

More info could be found in the [In-App Purchase Guidelines by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf).

Comment: Hi @Guido Hendriks, is eTicket considered as a digital content/service? I want to create a app to allow users to register for events and purchase tickets within the app. Will it get rejected by app store?

Answer (score 1):

-1 yes you can use the UIwebview

2- Apple get the 30% only from IAP and payed apps

better way to do is using SDK example [Paypal SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/)

Using an SDK helps you to control more what you want to display for the user and you can build your own brand payement UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion.